# Is $(x,y) \mapsto 0$ on $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$ associative and commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, binary-operations

I have the following definition of operations on the following sets:

1. $(x,y) \mapsto 9xy$ on $\mathbb{Z}$
2. $(x,y) \mapsto 0$ on $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$

I have to determine whether the operations on the given sets are associative, commutative, have a neutral element, and have inverse elements.

For $(x,y) \mapsto 9xy$ I have that it is associative, commutative, and has the neutral element $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, but does not have inverse elements as $(9xy)^{-1} \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Could you please help me with $(x,y) \mapsto 0$? I don't understand the operation. It always maps $(x,y) \mapsto 0$, so how do I prove if this is associative, commutative etc.?

Comment: For the first operation $1$ is not neutral element. Indeed, the neutral element does not exist. $(x,y)=x \implies 9xy=x$. For $x$ to be non-zero, $y$ does not have a unique solution in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is not consistent because $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$ are not disjoint : in that case a piecewise definite function has to coincide on the intersection which is not the case here. What is the value of $(1,1)$ ? is it $9$ or $0$ ?

Comment: @AlanWang Ahh ok, it's because of the constant $9$ right?

Comment: @Javiator Are there one or two exercises ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: Judging by the OP's wording of the problem, these are two problems, two different binary operations.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Exactly, two different operations

Comment: @Javiator, are you sure that the problem isn't: $(x,y) \mapsto 9xy$ when $x, y \in \Bbb Z$, and $(x,y) \mapsto 0$ when $x, y \in \Bbb Q \setminus \Bbb Z$?

Comment: @AlexM. I'm pretty sure it's $(x,y) \mapsto 0$ on $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$, it's copied from my text book on discrete maths.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, it is indeed associative and commutative because the usual multiplication of integers is som. It does not have a neutral element though, for the following reason: if $u \in \Bbb Z$ is this neutral element, then $9xu = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb Z$. For $x=1$ this would imply $9u = 1$, whence $u = \frac 1 9$ which is not in $\Bbb Z$.

For the second, $\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ is not even closed under the operation $(x,y) \mapsto 0$, so it makes no sense to speak about associativity and the rest.

Comment: Ok, I understand the first one not having a neutral element now. But for the second one: So it just does not fulfil any of the properties?

Comment: @Javiator: None of them, indeed, because every pair $(x,y)$ is taken into $0$, which no longer lives in $\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$, so you have no way of computing $(xy)z$ because this would mean $(0) z$ and this is not even defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is also associative because for all $x,y,z$:

$$0=(xy)z=x(yz)=0.$$

And it is also commutative because for all $x,y$:

$$0=xy=yx=0.$$

**Edit**

This proves that this law is associative and commutative on $\mathbb Q$.

Since the OP is considering this law on $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$, this is not an intern law because of instant $1\cdot 1=0 \notin \mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$. So the law is not well-defined on those sets.

Comment: No, it's not, because when computing $(xy)z$, since $xy = 0$ you may not write $(xy)z$, because that law is not defined when one of the arguments is $0$.

Comment: @AlexM. I edited to take account of your remark. Thanks for the comment, I didn't see that the law was only on $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ at first.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is associative and commutative as these two identities are homogeneous and then 
$$
(x,y)\rightarrow qxy
$$
is such on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Z}$. Only $q\in \{-1,1\}$ provides neutral.

The second is not even internal.